# What is the best way to get a part of a string from a given string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string in JavaScript like this:

```
var str = "1:A;2:B;3:A;4:c;5:D";
```

How to retreive option in front of `2`, that is `B`.

Presently am getting this using for loop by splitting the string every `;`,
but I want to know if there is any better way to achieve this without using looping concept.

Comment: Why, what's wrong with looping 'concept'?

Comment: my string may contain 2000 ";" , So I think  it will take some time to loop through 2000 elements

Comment: `"1:A;2:B;3:A;4:c;5:D".match(/2\:([A-Za-z]+?)\;/)[1];`

Comment: @KeerthiKumar no matter what you do, the computer will loop over the string, even if you don't see it in your code, javascript will do it internally at some point. Looping 2000 times is not a big deal for a computer.

Comment: @HamzaKubba First, my answer works fine for me. Second, looping through 2000 items may not be slow, but OP appears to feel it is inefficient and if there's another alternative. I would use RegExp from what I'm getting

Comment: @vihan1086 Your method won't work if str is this: "2:B;1:A". Also, regex matching uses loops, you just don't see them in the javascript code, but the computer is looping over the string to find the match.

Comment: Unless you have millions and millions of things to loop over, you should worry more about how readable your code is, instead of how efficient it is, because computers are very very fast at going through simple loops. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get the option in front of 2 you could use either:

1. a loop (preferred in my option)
2. `indexOf`

#### Javascript:

```
 function getAnswer(str) {

   var position = str.indexOf(';2:')

   // not found in string, or '2' is the first answer
   if(position === -1) {
     return;
   }

   return str.substring(position - 1, position)
 }
```

Comment: if the string started with 2:B then there would be no previous answer to get. Yes, you could fail more gracefully. I'll update

Answer (score 0):

#### RegExp

```
var num = '2';
"1:A;2:B;3:A;4:c;5:D".match((new RegExp(num+"\\:([\\S\\s]+?)\\;", "")))[1];
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wt3d2dr0/)

This uses RegExp *(Regular Expressions)* What this does is it will look for a '2' in the string, then get the option associated with it

#### Substring

I couldn't think of a  better word so forgive me. You can use substring and **`.indexOf()`**

```
var num = '2',
    string = "1:A;2:B;3:A;4:c;5:D",
    index = string.indexOf(num+':');
string.substring(index+num.length+1,index+num.length+2);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wt3d2dr0/1/)

#### Similar

The substring answer is a little easier to understand but the following does the same*ish*

```
var num = '2',
    string = "1:A;2:B;3:A;4:c;5:D";

string[string.indexOf(num+':')+num.length+1];
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wt3d2dr0/2/)

#### Foolproof

This should work in most situations. **This will also get the option if it is more than one letter long**

```
var string = "1:A;2:B;3:A;4:c;5:D",
    num = '2',
    result;

if (string.indexOf(';'+num+':') < 0) {
    result = string.match(new RegExp(num+"\\:([\\S\\s]+?)\\;", ""))[1];
} else {
    result = string.match((new RegExp('\\;'+num+"\\:([\\S\\s]+?)\\;", "")))[1];
}
```

Shorter:

```
var string = "1:A;2:B;3:A;4:c;5:D", num = '2', result = string.indexOf(";"+num+":") < 0? string.match(new RegExp(num+"\\:([\\S\\s]+?)\\;",""))[1] : string.match(new RegExp("\\;"+num+"\\:([\\S\\s]+?)\\;",""))[1];

alert(result);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wt3d2dr0/5/) *(I have made it a one-liner)*

Comment: If you check string.indexOf () for 21 also it will return some value rite? because number 2 is also present in 21

Comment: @KeerthiKumar That depends, That will return the position of the text '21' in the text

Comment: imagine your string is  1:A;20:B;10:A;21:B;2:C;22:A; Now if you do string.indexOf (2) will it return proper value??

Comment: @KeerthiKumar You need to string[string.indexOf(';2:')+2] you can use my Foolproof method and make number whatever you want. That will work 100% of the time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function, as below;

```
var str = "1:A;2:B;3:A;4:c;5:D";
var result = str.split(":");

document.getElementById("Location").innerHTML = res[2];
```

Comment: If he knew where the number was, then he can just do `document.getElementById("Location").innerHTML = 'B';`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that this will be a pattern you can use something like:

```js
var str = "1:A;2:B;3:A;4:c;5:D";
var i = 2;
console.log(str[str.indexOf(i)+2]);
//Output "B"
```

Comment: That's completely useless... if he knows the pattern ahead of time then he can just `console.log('B');`.

Comment: @HamzaKubba: He could know that there will be an index and want to know which letter is associated with the index, so it's not useless as you may think

Comment: He could, in another universe... if you read his question, that's not what he's asking for.

Comment: @HamzaKubba: He didn't say anything about the format of the string, if is ordered or not, if is `;` separated, and read more careful my answer, because is not the same that `console.log('B')`

Answer (score 0):

Might be recursive approach help you.

```
var str = "1:A;2:B;3:A;4:c;5:D",
    arr = str.split(";"),
    len = arr.length;

function getVal(len){
  if(len !== 0){
    getVal(len-1);
    if(arr[len-1].indexOf(2) === 0){
      console.log(arr[len-1].split(":")[1])
    };
  };
};

getVal(len);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems straight forward?

```
console.log(string.match(/(^|;)2:(\w*)/)[2]);
```